# Flutter Problem: How to navigate to another page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have a problem,My page is not going to homepage when i login,But why I dont know.
And the data is probably not coming in the submit fuction, then maybe that's why the login is not being done and I do not understand how the login will happen.

This is my auth.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Utils/api.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Utils/http_exception.dart';

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  var MainUrl = Api.authUrl;

  Future<void> Authentication(String user_name, String user_email,
      String mobile_no, String password, String action) async {
    try {
      // var url = Uri.parse('${MainUrl}/accounts:${endpoint}?key=${AuthKey}');
      var url = Uri.parse('$MainUrl&action=$action');
      print(url);
      if (action == 'registration') {
        final responce = await http.post(url, headers: {
          "Accept": "Application/json"
        }, body: {
          "user_name": user_name,
          'user_email': user_email,
          "mobile_no": mobile_no,
          "password": password,
        });

        print("Response" + responce.body);
        final responceData = json.decode(responce.body);
        print("responceData" + responceData);

      } else {
        final responce = await http.post(url, headers: {
          "Accept": "Application/json"
        }, body: {
          "user_name": user_name,
          'user_email': user_email,
          "username": mobile_no,
          "password": password,
        });

        print("Response" + responce.body);
        final responceData = json.decode(responce.body);
        print("responceData" + responceData);
       
      }


    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }

  Future<void> login(
      String user_name, String user_email, String mobile_no, String password) {
    return Authentication(user_name, user_email, mobile_no, password, 'login');
  }

  Future<void> signUp(
      String user_name, String user_email, String mobile_no, String password) {
    return Authentication(
        user_name, user_email, mobile_no, password, 'registration');
  }
}
```

This is my login.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Providers/auth.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Screens/home_screen.dart';
// import 'package:login_and_signup/Providers/login_auth.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Screens/signup.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Utils/http_exception.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  // static const String routeName = "/login";

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  TextEditingController _mobileController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'user_name': '',
    'user_email': '',
    'username': '',
    'password': ''
  };

  Future _submit() async {
    print('aa' + _authData['user_name']!);
    if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      //invalid

      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    try {
      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).login(
          _authData['user_name']!,
          _authData['user_email']!,
          _authData['username']!,
          _authData['password']!)  .then((_) {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
      });;
      print('aaaa');

    } catch (e) {
     
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(360),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(360)),
                    color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              Container(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Sign In",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Sign in with your username or email",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                    Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 20, right: 20),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "username",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              // obscureText: true,
                              controller: _mobileController,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.vpn_key,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 1) {
                                  return 'valid no';
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                _authData['username'] = value!;
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                           
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Password",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: _passwordController,
                              obscureText: true,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.vpn_key,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
                                  return 'Password is to Short';
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                _authData['password'] = value!;
                              },
                            ),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                              width: 140,
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    print(_authData['username']);
                                    print(_authData['password']);
                                    _submit();
                                  },
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Sign In',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.green),
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (ctx) => SignUpScreen()));
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 90),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Create Account",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        fontSize: 16),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showerrorDialog(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(
          'An Error Occurs',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        content: Text(message),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Okay'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my signup.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Providers/auth.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Providers/signup_auth.dart';
// import 'package:login_and_signup/Providers/signup_auth.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Screens/login.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Utils/http_exception.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'user_name': '',
    'user_email': '',
    'mobile_no': '',
    'password': '',
  };
  TextEditingController _nameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _emailController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _mobileController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  Future _submit() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      //invalid
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    try {
      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signUp(
          _authData['user_name']!,
          _authData['user_email']!,
          _authData['mobile_no']!,
          _authData['password']!)  .then((_) {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
      });;    } catch (e) {

    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(360),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(360)),
                    color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              Container(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Sign Up",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Sign up with username or email",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                    Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 20, right: 20),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "name",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              // obscureText: true,
                              controller: _nameController,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.person,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please Enter name';
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                _authData['user_name'] = value!;
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              " Email",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: _emailController,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.person,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                                  return 'Invalid email';
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                _authData['user_email'] = value!;
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "mobile",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              // obscureText: true,
                              controller: _mobileController,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.vpn_key,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 10) {
                                  return 'valid no';
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                _authData['mobile_no'] = value!;
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Password",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              controller: _passwordController,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.vpn_key,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
                                  return 'Password is to Short';
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                _authData['password'] = value!;
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Confirm Password",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.vpn_key,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value != _passwordController.text) {
                                  return 'Password doesnot match';
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                              width: 140,
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    print(_authData['mobile_no']);
                                    print(_authData['password']);
                                    _submit();
                                  },
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Sign Up',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.green),
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (ctx) => LoginScreen()));
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 90),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Sign In",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        fontSize: 16),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showerrorDialog(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(
          'An Error Occurs',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        content: Text(message),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Okay'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tested the log in page faking the Authentication and it seemed to work. Do you get any exception or something is not being printed?

Comment: No i dont get any exception.

Comment: Well, you can't get any exception as you have empty block catchs with is bad code. If you are not going to handle the exception it should just go through the app. Maybe you don't notice them

Answer (score 0):

what error are you getting when you tap of login?You can try to use a route generator class

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic>? generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    // Getting arguments passed in while calling Navigator.pushNamed
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/'://this will the first page get loaded
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage());
      case '/home':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyHomePage());
   }
  }

}

From  the main.dart call the initial page as follows
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',//
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,


    );

  }
}
```

call the other pages as

```
Navigator.of(context)
                .pushNamed('/home');
```

Comment: Please check this is one https://stackoverflow.com/q/68192605/15610685