# flutter problem : how to navigate to homepage from login

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

When I clicking on login then every time showing an error occurs in dialog box
[image]

but in my debug console my shown login successfully
[image]

I do not understand why login is not happening, it is throwing catch error again and again
While my login in deb console is succesfully

And after login should go to homepage.

this is my auth.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:rest_api_login/utils/api.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:rest_api_login/utils/http_exception.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  var MainUrl = Api.authUrl;
  var AuthKey = Api.authKey;

  // String _token;
  String _uid;
  String _username;
  DateTime _expiryDate;
  Timer _authTimer;

  bool get isAuth {
    return token != null;
  }

  String get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _uid != null) {
      return _uid;
    }
  }

  String get uid {
    return _uid;
  }

  String get username {
    return _username;
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    _username = null;
    _uid = null;
    _expiryDate = null;

    if (_authTimer != null) {
      _authTimer.cancel();
      _authTimer = null;
    }

    notifyListeners();

    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.clear();
  }

  void _autologout() {
    if (_authTimer != null) {
      _authTimer.cancel();
    }
    final timetoExpiry = _expiryDate.difference(DateTime.now()).inSeconds;
    _authTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: timetoExpiry), logout);
  }

  Future<bool> tryautoLogin() async {
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!pref.containsKey('userData')) {
      return false;
    }

    final extractedUserData =
        json.decode(pref.getString('userData')) as Map<String, Object>;

    final expiryDate = DateTime.parse(extractedUserData['expiryDate']);
    if (expiryDate.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
      return false;
    }

    _uid = extractedUserData['uid'];
    _username = extractedUserData['username'];
    _expiryDate = expiryDate;
    notifyListeners();
    _autologout();

    return true;
  }

  Future<void> Authentication(
      String username, String password, String endpoint) async {
    try {
      var url = Uri.parse('$MainUrl&action=$endpoint');

      final responce = await http.post(url,
          body: ({
            'username': username,
            'password': password,
          }));

      final responceData = json.decode(responce.body);
      print(responceData);
      if (responceData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responceData['error']['msg']);
      }

      _uid = responceData['uid'];
      _username = responceData['username'];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now()
          .add(Duration(seconds: int.parse(responceData['expiresIn'])));

      _autologout();
      notifyListeners();

      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final userData = json.encode({
        'uid': _uid,
        'username': _username,
        'expiryDate': _expiryDate.toIso8601String(),
      });

      prefs.setString('userData', userData);

      print('check' + userData.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }

  Future<void> login(String username, String password) {
    return Authentication(username, password, 'login');
  }

  Future<void> signUp(String username, String password) {
    return Authentication(username, password, 'registration');
  }
}
```

This is my login.dart page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:rest_api_login/providers/auth.dart';
import 'package:rest_api_login/screens/home_Screen.dart';
import 'package:rest_api_login/screens/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:rest_api_login/utils/http_exception.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/login";

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  Map<String, String> _authData = {'username': '', 'password': ''};

  Future _submit() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      //invalid
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    try {
      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
          .login(_authData['username'], _authData['password']);
    } on HttpException catch (e) {
      var errorMessage = 'Authentication Failed';
      if (e.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')) {
        errorMessage = 'Invalid email';
        _showerrorDialog(errorMessage);
      } else if (e.toString().contains('EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')) {
        errorMessage = 'This email not found';
        _showerrorDialog(errorMessage);
      } else if (e.toString().contains('INVALID_PASSWORD')) {
        errorMessage = 'Invalid Password';
        _showerrorDialog(errorMessage);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      var errorMessage = 'Plaese try again later';
      _showerrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(360),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(360)),
                    color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              Container(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Sign In",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Sign in with your username or email",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                    Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 20, right: 20),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Username or Email",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.person,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                              // validator: (value) {
                              //   if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                              //     return 'Invalid email';
                              //   }
                              // },
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                _authData['username'] = value;
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Password",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.vpn_key,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
                                  return 'Password is to Short';
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                _authData['password'] = value;
                              },
                            ),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                              width: 140,
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _submit();
                                  },
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Sign In',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.green),
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (ctx) => SignUpScreen()));
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 90),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Create Account",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        fontSize: 16),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showerrorDialog(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(
          'An Error Occurs',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        content: Text(message),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Okay'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my main.dart page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Providers/auth.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Providers/signup_auth.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Screens/login.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Screens/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Auth(),

      child: Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (context, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
          //home: LoginScreen(),
          home: auth.isAuth!
              ? HomeScreen()
              : FutureBuilder(
                  future: auth.tryautoLogin(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) =>
                      snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                          ? SplashScreen()
                          : LoginScreen()),
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

This is my homepage.dart page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Providers/auth.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Screens/login.dart';
// import 'package:login_signup_with_api/Providers/auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          
          child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
          Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).logout();
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: Text('logout'),
        color: Colors.green,
      )
          // color: Colors.green,
          // ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem could be in the `Auth` class, `LoginPage` or even `HomePage`.
Probably, the authentication is successful since you log it, but it could be that the exception is thrown when parsing the user information, rendering the screen, or something else.
Also, in your snippet, I cannot see exact place where you want to navigate to `HomeScreen`?

Comment: @Zpouip I updated my code please check it

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks

Comment: @zpouip please check it .

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint in your `catch` block, I tried to follow but for me, it looks quite ok.
Just add a breakpoint on the place where you call `_showerrorDialog(errorMessage);` and check the `error` object, then you might find the cause of it.

Comment: it may "Null check operator used on a null value" exception try to throw at _submit in catch like: 
 `catch (error) {
      var errorMessage = 'Plaese try again later';
      _showerrorDialog(errorMessage);
       rethrow;
    }`

Answer (score -1):

1. Error Handling in Login Screen:

```
    try {
         await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
             .login(_authData['username'], _authData['password']);
       } on HttpException catch (e) {
         _showerrorDialog(e.toString());
       } catch (error) {
         _showerrorDialog('An unexpected error occurred.');
       }
```

2. Navigation After Successful Login:

```
    try {
         await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
             .login(_authData['username'], _authData['password']);
         Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);
       } on HttpException catch (e) {
         _showerrorDialog(e.toString());
       } catch (error) {
         _showerrorDialog('An unexpected error occurred.');
       }
```

3. Debugging:

```
    Future<void> Authentication(
           String username, String password, String endpoint) async {
         try {
           var url = Uri.parse('$MainUrl&action=$endpoint');
           final responce = await http.post(url, body: {
             'username': username,
             'password': password,
           });
           final responceData = json.decode(responce.body);
           print('Authentication response: $responceData');
           // ... rest of the code
         } catch (e) {
           print('Authentication error: $e');
           throw e;
         }
       }

    Future<void> _submit() async {
         // ... existing code
         try {
           await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
               .login(_authData['username'], _authData['password']);
           print('Login successful');
           Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);
         } on HttpException catch (e) {
           print('Login error: $e');
           _showerrorDialog(e.toString());
         } catch (error) {
           print('Login unexpected error: $error');
           _showerrorDialog('An unexpected error occurred.');
         }
       }
```